# Declare (define) Class member methods

Tags: typescript, es6-class

I have TypeScript ES6 Class, suppose it looks like this

```
class Classic
    private _member: Object;
    constructor(member: Object) {
       this._member = member;
    }
}
```

And I have some rich object, that contains a lot of methods, which I want to inherit, but that object is not a TS or ES6 Class, it's just POJO (ObjectLiteral).

So I made quick and dirty inheritance like

```
Object.assign(Classic.prototype, ObjectLiteralWithMethods);
```

No need for deep copy, everything works.

**How can I tell TypeScript that `Classic` has these inherited methods and specify their behavior?**

I searched for keywords like declare OR define AND class AND method, but my google-fu is not sufficient.

I tried define interface for `Classic`, but it did not work either.

I tried to declare class like

```
declare class ObjectLiteralWithMethods {
    public method(): void;
    protected _method(parameter: string): void;
}
```

and then extend that declaration like

```
class Classic extends ObjectLiteralWithMethods { ... }
```

but then TypeScript wants me to call `super()` in `constructor`, which fails.

I know that I can implement "dummy" methods on `Classic` like

```
class Classic {
    dummyMethodImplementation(param: string): string {
        return param;
    }
}
```

but this would be painfull and inefficient. I just want to define/declare that class `Classic` is extended.

### SOLVED

Sort of...

The `ObjectLiteralWithMethods` in my case was actually a prototype for jQuery widget. So, I extended the owner of the prototype.

It needed some patching, because TS was not aware of the owner so I made:

```
// declaring the properties and methods which will be inherited by my class
declare class JQueryUIWidget {
    public property: string;
    public method(): string;
    ...
}

// must declare a constructor for JQueryUIWidget to be able to extend
// and cast the value to any, so TS do not mind
const Widget: { new (): JQueryUIWidget } = $.Widget as any;

// and then extend that declaration
class Classic extends Widget {
    constructor() {
        super(); // super(); is mandatory here, with plain object it 
                 // did not worked, but since Widget is in fact a Function
                 // it works now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I had a similar requirement when converting parts of a legacy system to TypeScript, so this might help somebody else.

If you know your class will be enhanced at runtime with other methods and you simply want to have type information and intellisense available for those methods, AND you don't want to write ugly stubs, you can try this:

First, define your interface(s) detailing the runtime methods:

```
interface RuntimeImplementedType {
    public method(): void;
}

interface AnotherRuntimeImplementedType {
    public other_method(): void;
}
```

Then define a variable whose type is specified as a constructor function returning the union of the types that you want to inform TypeScript your class implements at runtime. Assign the variable a function returning an empty object literal, casting to "any" so as to avoid compiler grumbles and ensure that when transpiled, what is actually being extended is just a plain old empty object.

```
const Base: new() => RuntimeImplementedType & AnotherRuntimeImplementedType = (() => {}) as any;
```

Now define your new class, extending from your constructor function variable:

```
class Classic extends Base {
    public doSomething() {
        this.method();
        this.other_method();
    }
}
```

All methods from the interfaces should be available, but without having to actually provide an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
declare class ObjectLiteralWithMethods {
    public method(): void;
    public _method(parameter: string): void;
}

class Classic implements ObjectLiteralWithMethods {
    private _member: Object;

    constructor(member: Object) {
       this._member = member;
    }

    method: () => void;
    _method: (parameter: string) => void;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20class%20ObjectLiteralWithMethods%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20method()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_method(parameter%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Classic%20implements%20ObjectLiteralWithMethods%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_member%3A%20Object%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(member%3A%20Object)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._member%20%3D%20member%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_method%3A%20(parameter%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D))

But you won't be able to use protected members/methods in `ObjectLiteralWithMethods` because you are using it as an interface.

---

#### Edit

If you need to override methods in `Classic` in a subclass then you'll need to use stabs for the methods:

```
class Classic implements ObjectLiteralWithMethods {
    private _member: Object;

    constructor(member: Object) {
       this._member = member;
    }

    method() {};
    _method(parameter: string) {}
}

class Other extends Classic {
    method() {

    }
}
```

The methods in `Classic` are empty, and you override them with the implementation in ObjectLiteralWithMethods.

Comment: I did not express my true motivation for this -- I want to overcome a necessity to implement methods on `Classic`, because they are replaced from POJO. I just want to declare, that such methods exists and define its type definition.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. And `method` and `_method` have no implementation in `Classic`, just the signatures.

Comment: Sorry, I did not registered colon ˙:˙. But this makes me some more trouble. I further extend `Classic` to some `SubClassics` and I got an error: *Classic defines instance member property, but SubClassic defines it as instance member function*.

Comment: I'm currently making a dummy implementation of methods, like you proposing. That way I do not even need `Classic implements  ObjectLiteralWithMethods` because all signatures are defined in `Classic`. This has one drawback -- JS engine has to create all the dummy functions, which are latter replaced with `Object.assign()`, just to aware TypeScript that such methods exists. That is inefficient. I basically just need to extend `Classic` type with signatures of methods, that I know, will be inherited from POJO.

Comment: How many such methods do you have? If we're not talking about A LOT then creating these dummy functions shouldn't be a concern in my opinion.

Comment: You are right, but defining `class` extension is everything I need, making dummy functions because of this is uglier than [fiat multipla](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d2/0b/fc/d20bfc703a51f75f69f0ab80a62e1cbb.jpg). I opened a question/proposal on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13563).

Comment: I doubt that it will help you. You are doing something eccentric/esoteric and I don't think that they'll support it

Comment: I think that possibility to extend class type is quite legitimate, although even I admit, that the way I extended the class is ugly. Probably more uglier than [working for the asian military](http://cdn.trinixy.ru/pics4/20090908/work_safe_31.jpg).

Comment: Well, you can extend normal classes with no problem. In your case, I'd say that the better approach is [Composition over inheritance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Composition_over_inheritance). Just have that object as a member of your class and call its methods when needed. But looks like they accepted your issue as a bug.

Comment: Trying `interface` approach was my instinctive move. It seems like the guys from TS have similar feeling, that this way it shall be hackable. It's amazing how quick they respond. Many thanks also to you for your effort. It wont be forgotten.